# how to collaborate two folders on the same box account on boxapi?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, sdk, box-api

I am new to box API, how to collaborate two folders on the same box account or share the files or folders on same box account using rest API

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use the collaborations endpoints to add all users that need access to the files / folders. Here's some info on that:

- [Sharing files with users via the collaboration endpoint](https://developer.box.com/en/guides/collaborations/share-file/).
- [Sharing folders with users via the collaboration endpoint](https://developer.box.com/en/guides/collaborations/share-folder/).

[This handy chart](https://community.box.com/t5/Collaborate-By-Inviting-Others/Understanding-Collaborator-Permission-Levels/ta-p/144) shows what each collaboration level will get access to, so use that as a reference when you're collaborating a user in on a file / folder.

Since you've tagged this as PHP, I would also like to mention that there are no official PHP SDKs. We do however have a number of PHP / Laravel wrappers under our [community projects](https://developer.box.com/en/support/community-projects/#sdks-and-wrappers).

Comment: hi thanks for your feedback, but if we follow these steps to collaborate only one folder

Comment: @balamurugannatarajan you'll call the collaboration endpoint twice, once for each folder.